# Complexity computation of a determinant recursive algorithm

Tags: recursion, big-o, complexity-theory

I have written an algorithm to compute the determinant of `n x n` matrix, base on Laplace Expansion:

[image: equation]

I got the recurrence relation below:
`T(n) = n(n² + T(n-1))`

I read in Wikipedia that this should yield the result `T(n) = O(n!)`, but I don't know how to prove that (although it's intuitive).

Comment: It's not a recurrence relation if T doesn't appear on the right.

Comment: I'm sorry the F should have been T. I've change that

Comment: The way you wrote it it's not O(n!). T(n)=nT(n-1)=O(n!). Yours is much bigger

Comment: @icepack try to build the function that represent the recurrance relation (pretty simple - something like 3 lines).
After that, compute f(i+1)/f(i) for big values of i (i think even i=5 would be good enough). You'll notice that f(i+1)/f(i) = i+1. I'm pretty sure it means that f(n) = O(n!). Notice that I don't claim the f(n) equals n!, but asimptotically 'behave' like n!.

Comment: T(n)=n(n^2+T(n-1))=n^3+n(T(n-1))=n^3+n[(n-1)^3+(n-1)T(n-2)]=... - seems that with each iteration the maximal(dominant) power of n raises by 1, so that at the end it yields O(n^n).

Comment: @icepack n! = n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*1 => O(n!) = O(n^n) ?

Comment: Are you sure that formula is correct? The summations seem to only be over one of i and j, but both variables are being used.

Answer (score 4):

The formula is correct but your recurrence relation is not. You do not need the `n²`, since you don't have to save or generate the sub matrices.

`Mij` is the determinant of an `(n-1) x (n-1)` sub matrix. So you have to compute `n` determinants of `n` different matrices. So the correct recurrence relation is `T(n) = n⋅T(n-1) + 2n-1`. This simplifies to

```
T(n) = n ⋅ T(n-1) + 2n-1
     = n ⋅ (n-1) ⋅ T(n-2) + n ⋅ (n-1)
     = n ⋅ ( (n-1) ⋅ ( (n-2) ⋅ (...) + n-3 ) + n-2 ) + n-1
     = 2n-1 + n ⋅ (2(n-1)-1) + n ⋅ (n-1) ⋅ (2(n-2)-1) + ... + n!
     < 2 ⋅ n + 2 ⋅ n ⋅ (n-1) + 2 ⋅ n ⋅ (n-1) ⋅ (n-2) + ... + 2 ⋅ n! + n!
     = 2 ⋅ (n + n ⋅ (n-1) + ... + n!/2) + 3 ⋅ n!
     < 2 ⋅ (n!/(n-1)! + n!/(n-2)! + ... + n!/2!) + 3 ⋅ n!
```

Due to `2⋅n!/k! ≤ n!/(k-1)!` for all `k ≥ 2`, we get

```
  n!/(n-1)! + n!/(n-2)! + n!/(n-3)! + ... + n!/2!
≤ n!/(n-2)! + n!/(n-2)! + n!/(n-3)! + ... + n!/2!
≤ n!/(n-3)! + n!/(n-3)! + ... + n!/2!
≤ n!/(n-4)! + ... + n!/2!
≤ ...
≤ n!/2! + n!/2!
≤ n!
```

And so

```
T(n) = n ⋅ T(n-1) + 2n-1
     < 2 ⋅ (n!/(n-1)! + n!/(n-2)! + ... + n!/2!) + 3 ⋅ n!
     ≤ 2 ⋅ n! + 3 ⋅ n!
     = 5 ⋅ n!
     = O(n!)
```

So your algorithm runs in `O(n!)`